# typing dynamically created function

Tags: typescript

Given the following code:

```js
class Service {
  actions: Record<string, Function>;
}

class ServiceRunner<S extends typeof Service> {
  #service: Service
  constructor(ServiceClass: S) {
    this.#service = new ServiceClass();
    for (const [actionName, actionFn] of Object.entries(this.#service.actions)) {
      this[actionName] = (...args: any[]) => actionFn(...args);
    }
  }
}

class Foo extends Service {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("constructor of Foo")
  }
  actions: {
    action1: () => {};
    action2: (id: string) => {};
  };
  anotherMethodThatIsNotAnAction() {}
}

const runner = new ServiceRunner(Foo)
runner.action1(); // My goal would be to have completion and typing on "action1" here
runner.action2("ok") // the same
```

As you may see, I dynamically build some functions in the `ServiceRunner` which are directly mapped to the given inner `Service` ones. It works (the javascript code runs right), but I don't have any clue to type those functions in order that they are equivalent to those defined in the `Foo` service (or any given descendent of `Service`).

I don't even know if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

A class can have an index signature, but it can't have a staticly typed members that aren't declared with the class.

I would caution you against this approach if `ServiceRunner` has other members that do not come from the service class as name collisions can occur.

You ca get this to work in TS however if you create a separate constructor signature that creates the corect type for the  returned instance:

```
type ServiceRunner<S extends Service> = ServiceRunnerBase & S['actions']
const ServiceRunner = ServiceRunnerBase as new <S extends Service>(ServiceClass: new () => S) => ServiceRunner<S>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=6&pln=10&pc=38#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCmAnAbgS2PaBvAsAKGmjGABdUB7AOwgEIAuaAJXmHMQBMAeCExVSgOYAaaADEArpVIVKAPgDc+AL758oSDAQp08RpMpIAQpEy4C0AMQQkaDAy234+Qq2q9xpNgAoHOgMLgUAwkAJ4ADvDkAGZwNjoAlNjOhNAkABaoEAB0VnEY0AC80AYA7rHaGAEaXvGK5oRRbNBerjzQANrEZFQAcmAAtvAiXTKilAC60NHQAPIARgBWLCRZ8JS8qPAQXumZOdYV8FkjVBDxiWYpKTsZMJBElCHxndK9A-CTRV5ZP2CIAhAGGBHu1xokCrIiK9KGNvr9-mc6lcVOYUSj8KEIuVHHpKAZEJxYNB4AAPEhrdiaPLwSFFXwYXH44zWaAAMjg7QA5CdqJzxmpTiRsTpGUhCsKGfojCYiDBStBCcSyRSqYdZD5qVUgsV4GUaoVIbBwYbqaKCbBZKo8GpAjBRORyEryZRKRLTMlWu5PIh9ZcUhBxBEfbVki5TuQQEcQOQBF4AESexAeEhNab28hx+LJFGEHm0Bh+3PQgCMDH1EOwSiRKR5ACYy6h2AweHxBMbK9Wq8lgeR0kgALLwdLkdgAFTSYBIAEkID1ewBBSjz6G+tFWz3QJN4sVFeX03RSn3prN4Lf444lmryaAAehv0H7IWgAnIYBA0BK5HEIHY0DmmBTaAJ2QTBWH6MJI26SgHl-TF+AEKZoLjHlizjICkCcU9DwvKDa3jcgAGtM1ve8+2gCB3iAA)

If you don't have any extra members in `ServiceRunner` you could also simplify this to:

```
type ServiceRunner<S extends Service> = S['actions']
const ServiceRunner = ServiceRunnerBase as new <S extends Service>(ServiceClass: new () => S) => ServiceRunner<S>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCmAnAbgS2PaBvAsAKGmjGABdUB7AOwgEIAuaAJXmHMQBMAeCExVSgOYAaaADEArpVIVKAPgDc+AL758oSDAQp08RpMpIAQpEy4C0AMQQkaDAy234+QgG1KYALbwGPPoIC6DBJSZFSK5qzUvOKkbAAUDjoAwuBQDCQAngAO8OQAZnA2OgCU2M6E0CQAFqgQAHRWRRjQALzQBgDuhdoYKRpxxeEV0Hls0HGRPNAuxKGUAHKe8CKzMqKU-tD50ADyAEYAViwkdfCUvKjwEHHVtQ3WPfB1q1QQxaVmw4S3EDPSVIsvJs2nE6mCwIgBBAGGBKBkXP5Si1ZER-pR1qDwZC3kMKipzPj8fhMjluo49JQDIhOLBoPAAB4kM7sTRNeAotqwFwAche1G5-jUrxIZJ0FKprVFGHFRhMRBgnWgNLpjOZrMesgSbL6aXa8C6A1aKNgSONbJl1NgslUeDUqRgonI5BVTMoLKlpnKk2isUQhs+FQg4hyfsG5UIk3IICeIHIAjiACJvYgYiQxttHeQE8VyvjCHzaAwA-m0QBGBiG5HYJS4ktzABMFdQ7B8F0EpuruJr5Vh5GqSAAsvBquR2AAVKpgEgASQg8z7AEFKAu0f7CTbvdAU5SkJLFYlpfokHFMzm8Nuqc8ywN5NAAPR36ADjLQATkMAgaAdcjiEDsaB7JgabQJOyCYKwHhZNGcxEG6lTZPwAhbJQ0AJnypYJiBSBOOeR6IFeDaJuQADW2b3o+-bQBASxAA)